# How to show only 1 image of multiple-image field in Flickr API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My code is in this codepen.io link:
http://codepen.io/ChocolateRoca/pen/jrpjPp

When I type a random city name into a search bar, the code uses the city name as a tag to look up related images through Flickr's API.

Flickr API link: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?

The link, in its callback, provides a response in this format:

```
    jQuery31009750922804659352_1477691108443({
    "title": "Recent Uploads tagged boston",
    "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/boston/",
    "description": "",
    "modified": "2016-10-28T22:36:35Z",
    "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
    "items": [
   {
        "title": "Wilmington, Vermont.....on the way to Boston",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/mishlove1/30327590520/",
        "media": {"m":"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5695/30327590520_a7e599c963_m.jpg"},
        "date_taken": "2016-10-03T07:44:18-08:00",
        "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/mishlove1/\">mishlove1<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/mishlove1/30327590520/\" title=\"Wilmington, Vermont.....on the way to Boston\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5695/30327590520_a7e599c963_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"Wilmington, Vermont.....on the way to Boston\" /><\/a><\/p> <p>Wilmington, Vermont......on the road and on the way to Boston<\/p>",
        "published": "2016-10-28T22:36:35Z",
        "author": "nobody@flickr.com (mishlove1)",
        "author_id": "45049047@N04",
        "tags": "boston canada canon canon7d cityofboston jamaicaplain michaelishlove roadtrip usa"
   },
   {
        "title": "Wilmington, Vermont.....on the way to Bosto",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/mishlove1/30510706342/",
        "media": {"m":"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5720/30510706342_b9de69d877_m.jpg"},
        "date_taken": "2016-10-03T08:09:03-08:00",
        "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/mishlove1/\">mishlove1<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/mishlove1/30510706342/\" title=\"Wilmington, Vermont.....on the way to Bosto\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5720/30510706342_b9de69d877_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"Wilmington, Vermont.....on the way to Bosto\" /><\/a><\/p> <p>Wilmington, Vermont.....on the road and on the way to Boston<\/p>",
        "published": "2016-10-28T22:36:34Z",
        "author": "nobody@flickr.com (mishlove1)",
        "author_id": "45049047@N04",
        "tags": "boston canada canon canon7d cityofboston jamaicaplain michaelishlove roadtrip usa"
   },....


 })
```

Within the code, this code allows me to display all the images within the Flickr Api and related tag.

```
    function FlickerResponse(respond) {
    var photosHTML;
    var photosHTML = respond.items.reduce(function(InitialOrPrevious,CurrentValue) {
        InitialOrPrevious += [
            '<a href="', CurrentValue.link, '">',
            '<img src="' + CurrentValue.media.m + '">',
            '</a>'
        ].join(' ');

        return InitialOrPrevious;
    }, '');
    $("#quotediv").html(photosHTML);
  };
```

BUT I can't figure out how to display only the first image within the API Link:
I've tried replacing "CurrentValue.link" and "CurrentValue.media.m" with "respond.items[0].link" and "respond.items[0].media.m" but it only repeats images, rather than print the first (and only one) image in the Flickr API link.

Comment: You can directly access the first image object with `respond.items[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` you got have 20 items in `respond.items`.

The "quick&dirty" way is to change:

```
respond.items.reduce(function...
```

To:

```
respond.items.slice(0,1).reduce(function...
```

This way you take only the first element of the Array and run the function on it.

Another option is to do this change:

```
var photo = respond.items[0]
var photoHTML = '<a href="'+ photo.link +'"><img src="'+ photo.media.m +'"></a>'
$('#quotediv').html(photoHTML);
```

This way you don't run the function on the array, you just take the first photo and create the html you need from it.